# Failed to move existing Opencart project to a new local server

Tags: php, wamp, opencart

I can't run my existing Opencart project in a new workstation.
Here's what it says when I try to open my project. By the way I already included the database and I am using a wampserver.

Here's my errors:

```
Warning: fopen(C:\wamp\www\myshops/system/logs/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\myshops\system\library\log.php on line 6

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\myshops\index.php on line 101
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0023  485984  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.1002  2039896 Front->dispatch( )  ..\index.php:272
3   0.1028  2122968 Front->execute( )   ..\front.php:29
4   0.1028  2122968 Action->execute( )  ..\front.php:34
5   0.1042  2171896 call_user_func ( )  ..\vq2-system_engine_action.php:65
6   0.1042  2171912 ControllerCommonHome->index( )  ..\vq2-system_engine_action.php:65
7   0.1043  2172472 Loader->controller( )   ..\home.php:12
8   0.1046  2173216 Action->execute( )  ..\vq2-system_engine_loader.php:12
9   0.1060  2245240 call_user_func ( )  ..\vq2-system_engine_action.php:65
10  0.1060  2245256 ControllerCommonContentLeft->index( )   ..\vq2-system_engine_action.php:65
11  0.1167  2421624 Loader->view( ) ..\content_left.php:177
12  0.1170  2410552 Log->__destruct( )  ..\log.php:0
13  0.1170  2410584 fclose ( )  ..\log.php:14
14  0.1170  2411096 error_handler( )    ..\log.php:14
```

I am using Windows 7 in my development.

Comment: I would say you missed a file when you copied things to the new machine

Comment: "fopen(C:\wamp\www\myshops/system/logs/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory" says that there may be the logs directory missing.You can also zip the whole project on the old workstation and unzip it on the new one.

Comment: FYI: www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2016/01/19/16

Answer (score 0):

Double check your path manually of WAMP server

```
C:\wamp\www\
```

Also modify your both config files on root as well as on admin

```
myshops/config
myshops/admin/config
```

If it still create issues put this on your config file and run your project

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

and find `SCRIPT_FILENAME` than check the path you provided in config files is same as its shows in `SCRIPT_FILENAME`